# Offside behind the goalkeeper

Tags: rules, football

Found this video on facebook where a goal was cancelled because there was offside behind the goalkeeper. I don't know whether the video was fake or not.

[image]

What is the rule of this situation?

Answer (score 3):

[The Law](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/offside/) is the same as it always is:

> A player is in an offside position if: [...] any part of the head, body or feet is nearer to the opponents’ goal line than both the ball and the second-last opponent

The goalkeeper is not "special" in any way in the offside law: there must be two opponents closer to the goal-line than the player when the ball is played. In the screenshot in your question, there is only one opponent closer to the goal-line so it was correctly ruled offside.